# 12.04 sandybridge cpu high heat

Tags: intel, overheating

My 2500K sandybridge cpu seems to hover around 75-80C when doing light web browsing. Is this a problem in the kernel for 12.04(and is there a fix/workaround for it?) or should I look into a better cooler and thermal paste?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the 12.04 kernel which I read has been fixed in 12.10 kernel. Best option is probably manage the situation until 12.10 is released in 3 weeks or so. Hope this helps